# Cannot read /data/data/com.packagename in android rooted device

Tags: android, root

I am working on an app and I have to read a package name from /data/data folder in a rooted device.

I have tried the following code, but it is not able to read that file. Although, many of root file explorer apps are able to read and change these folders.

I am using google pixel2 with android 11 and in pixel 4 with android 13.

```
 "su",
        "chmod 777 /",
        "chmod 777 " + Environment.getDataDirectory(),
        "chmod 777 " +Environment.getDataDirectory()+ "/data/",
        "chmod 777 " +Environment.getDataDirectory()+ "/data/com.packagename"
    )
    try {
        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
        val out = DataOutputStream(process.outputStream)
        for (str in arr) out.writeBytes(
            """$str""".trimIndent())
        out.writeBytes("exit\n")
        out.flush()
        val proc = process.waitFor()
        Log.d("MYAPPINFOTA", proc.toString())

       // Log.d("MYAPPINFOTA", file.listFiles().size.toString())
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
```